# jTable, overwritten DefaultCellRenderer won't redraw icons after sort

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, imageicon

I have a problem using a `jTable` with the `DefaultTableModel`.

I got two columns that display an icon using an overwritten `DefaultTableCellRenderer`:

```
private static ImageIcon errorIcon = new ImageIcon("workDir/icons/error.png");
private static ImageIcon pageIcon = new ImageIcon("workDir/icons/page_white.png");
private static ImageIcon serverIcon = new ImageIcon("workDir/icons/server_go.png");
private static ImageIcon acceptIcon = new ImageIcon("workDir/icons/accept.png");

private class ImageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {  

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel();

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        //lbl.setText((String) value);
        lbl.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        if (value.equals("e")) {
            lbl.setIcon(pageIcon);
            return lbl;
        }

        ServiceTicket t = TICKET_DICT.get((UUID) tableModel.getValueAt(row, 3));

        if (t == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find Ticket for UUID");
        }

        if (t.getReport().getElsterCode().equals("0")) {
            if (t.getSendMode().equals(EricSendMode.VALIDATE_LOCALLY)) {
                lbl.setIcon(acceptIcon);
            } else {
                lbl.setIcon(serverIcon);
            }
        } else {
            lbl.setIcon(errorIcon);
        }

        lbl.repaint();
        return lbl;
    }
}
```

I set `ImageRenderer` during the init phase of the view:

```
    resultTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
    resultTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
```

I want my table to be sortable. So I used this line to enable default sorting:

```
resultTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

My problem is now that sorting works well, but the icons in column 0 and 4 are not redrawn after a sort event.

I tried adding an event to tell the table that the cell values have changed, but that did not work:

```
    resultTable.getRowSorter().addRowSorterListener(
            new RowSorterListener() {

                @Override
                public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {                        
                    if (e.getType().equals(RowSorterEvent.Type.SORTED)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
                            tableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(i, 0);
                            tableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(i, 4);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
```

Can you help me get the icons redrawn after the table is sorted. I checked the table model and all cells and columns get sorted correctly. Even the values in the cells that get rendered as an icon.

Thanks!

Comment: *never-ever* even think of firing events on behalf of the model: a well-behaved implemenation must fire them as appropriate. Even worse: doing so in a sorterListener could well produce an endless loop ...

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks! I produced StackOverFlowExceptions during another approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks which are not really an answer, but too long for a comment.

```
ServiceTicket t = TICKET_DICT.get((UUID) tableModel.getValueAt(row, 3));
```

will retrieve the incorrect value from the `TableModel` when the table is sorted. At that point, the `row` index which is passed does not match the element at index `row` in the model (due to the sorting).

Use the `JTable#convertRowIndexToModel` to convert the index to a model index.

Further, the listener which calls `fireTableCellUpdated` when the sorter is changed is not needed, and even incorrect. While the table might change the order in which the elements are displayed, nothing has changed to the underlying data.

And last

> I checked the table model and all cells and columns get sorted correctly. Even the values in the cells that get rendered as an icon

Not sure what you mean by 'checked the table model'. Nothing changes to the `TableModel` when you sort. Sorting only happens on the view side, not on the model side.

Comment: _event firing code after sorting is not necessary_ ehhh ... it's completely wrong (as _you_ know :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I rephrased that sentence. Hopefully it is more clear now